# New WeibullR package producing Incorrect Weibull Plot

Tags: r, plot, weibull

I have the following data points for which I have generated a weibull plot as follows

```
 library(weibullR)
 left<-c( 36.0, 35.0 ,34.0 ,33.0 ,32.0 ,31.0, 30.0 ,32.5 ,35.5 ,29.5 ,28.5, 30.5, 26.5, 31.5, 20.5 ,34.5, 25.5, 10.5, 27.5, 18.5, 33.5,  2.5 ,11.5 ,23.5, 22.5 ,13.5 , 9.5 ,24.5 ,21.5,15.5, 16.5, 14.5 ,17.5, 19.5 , 0.5,  8.5,6.5)
 right<-c( -1.0, -1.0 ,-1.0 ,-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0 ,32.5, 35.5 ,29.5, 28.5, 30.5, 26.5, 31.5,20.5, 34.5, 25.5, 10.5,27.5 ,18.5, 33.5,  2.5 ,11.5, 23.5 ,22.5 ,13.5 , 9.5 ,24.5, 21.5,15.5, 16.5 ,14.5, 17.5, 19.5,  0.5 , 8.5,  6.5)
 qty<-c( 65416,29,16,7,4,2,1,45,62,21,26,34,20,41,5,44,14,2,20,6,50,1,3,21,13,7,1, 
 7,13,4,4,2,5,2,1,1,1)
 state<-c( 0 ,0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ,1 ,1, 1, 1 ,1 ,1 ,1, 1 ,1, 1 ,1 ,1, 1 ,1 ,1, 1 
 ,1, 1 ,1 ,1 ,1, 1 ,1, 1 ,1)

The above four represent the input parameters
ci<-0.9# Confidence 
dist= "weibull2p" ##Distribution type
weibull_fit<-mlefit(data.frame(left,right,qty),dist =dist)## This generates the weibulll parameters-Beta, Eta etc 
da1<-wblr(data.frame(time=left,event =state,qty=qty)) 
da1 <- wblr.fit(da1 ,dist= dist,method.fit="mle",pch=3)
#### BLCOK IN CASE OF 3 P
da1<-wblr.conf(da1,method.conf="fm",ci=as.numeric(ci),col="Red")
df <-da1$data$dpoints
df <- df[!duplicated(df[ , c("time")]),]
da1$data$dpoints <- df 
par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))
p1<-plot(da1) 
p1
```

The plot p1 shows a different set of parameters in the legend and the plot appears- beta , eta and loglikelihood are different and the censored data are missing. I am using R version 4.2.1 and weibullR  1.2.1. The code I have used works well in weibullR 1.1.10. I request someone to guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version seems to have problems with the suspension. In my case in a data frame like:

```r
y <- data.frame(time=c(1,2,3),event=c(1,0,1),qty=c(1,1,1))
```

the suspensions are ignored. Without the qty column it works however if you have large numbers of suspensions you cannot omit the qty colum. I suppose it is a bug.